# По каким причинам поток не может быть создан?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, потоки-данных, распараллеливание

Нужен теоретический ответ на то, по каким причинам при создании потока внутри программы, он не будет создан. То есть какие в теории могут произойти сбои и нарушения работы, в результате которых поток не создастся.

Comment: система не поддерживает потоки? или просто не хватает ресурсов, что бы создать поток? или система так загружена, что она просто ещё не успела создать поток, но она его создаст, через час. Но для Вас она его "не создала".

Comment: Пусть например у нас система Windows, она поддерживает многопоточность. Правильно ли я понимаю, что единственной причиной невозможности создать поток, может быть только высокая загруженность ? или могут быть другие причины конкретно на винде ?

Comment: к примеру, могла закончится память. А может просто глюкануло. Думаю, что у Вас случился странный баг и Вы пытаетесь зайти вот так. Может расскажете проблему?

Comment: См. ***ERRORS*** в [man pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)

Comment: В том то и дело что на практике я не сталкивался с такой ситуацией, вопрос университетский на защиту, а в лекционных материалах найти ответ не удалось, как и серфин в сети не дал особых результатов. 

Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Тогда вам сначала, например, [сюда](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/thread), а потом в kernel